# Remove apostrophe in string values in nested list

Tags: python, date

When I convert my dataframe to list, I get the below reponse. I want to remove the apostrophes i.e. `'Date(2018,11,09)'` should look like `Date(2018,11,09)`.

```
new_df = df.values.tolist()
```

**Output-**

```
[[68.0, 86.0, 'Date(2018, 11, 09)'], [40.0, 56.0, 'Date(2018, 11, 10)'], [34.0, 25.0, 'Date(2018, 11, 11)'].......]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443308/remove-apostrophe-around-items-in-nested-list-in-python) is close to what I'm looking for but in my scenario, it is not an integer.

**Desired output -**

```
[[68.0, 86.0, Date(2018, 11, 09)], [40.0, 56.0, Date(2018, 11, 10)], [34.0, 25.0, Date(2018, 11, 11)].......]
```

**Datatype -**

```
             Sender 
Message        User1    float64
               User2    float64
js_ready_date              object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Well, it’s in quotes because it is a string right?  So you want to convert it to some date Object?

Comment: What are the data types of your dataframe?  `df.dtypes`

Comment: Yes the datatype for 3rd column is string here. I just want the output to be without `'`. Datatype can be anything

Comment: The `dtype` of the column with `Date(2018, 11, 09)` is a string in the dataframe?  Can you post an example of your input data?

Comment: It seems it is an object and not string. My bad. Added the results in post

Comment: What are you planning to use the output for?

Comment: The [Google Chart library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes) accepts date in that particular format. I am passing this dataframe via flask to my html page.

Answer (score 3):

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without) might be helpful.

Python interpreter returns a string with quotes.

```
>>> a = [68.0, 86.0, 'Date(2018, 11, 09)']
>>> a[2]
'Date(2018, 11, 09)'
>>> print(a[2])
Date(2018, 11, 09)
```

Therefore if you use a string in Python, there is no other way to store a string without quotes.